# Connect azure website to azure sql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-security

In our current on-prem world we rely on Windows authentication. Each IIS app pool runs under identity of a service account. And this service account has dbo permissions on sql database. How can I establish this similar (i know same is not possible) security model for Azure PaaS website?

I referred [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) link which talks about sql authentication however I couldn't find anything relevant to my scenario in there. Any ideas on how others are dealing with this?

Comment: Couldn't you just create an SQL user for the app with certain rights?

Comment: I thought of doing something similar. But then the problem is of password which will be stored as part of connectionstring in website's environment settings and application developer can view it which violates our security especially production one.

Comment: As I know Azure SQL supports "SQL Server Authentication","AD Password Authentication","AD intergrated Authentication" ways currently. Seems there is no similar security model for Azure WebApp. Maybe you could use CloudService and Azure SQL server (SQL server installed in the VM)and set custom domain in the azure environment,if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Azure Active Directory and then integrated this with your Azure SQL Database? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access-aad-authentication-get-started

Comment: Is **Active Directory password authentication** the answer for me? Can this be related to my scenario in my original post question?